# While Uploading and importing very large data file(CSV) Adding " in all the column

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to upload csv files to a table with following query

```
mysqli_query($cons, '
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE "crypto/blog/csv/' . $file . '"
    INTO TABLE ' . $table . '
    FIELDS TERMINATED by \',\'
    LINES TERMINATED BY \'\n\'
 ');
```

It is saving all the data, No problem but it is adding  quates (") in starting and end of all the columns Ex

"London"

whats wrong with my query.

Comment: Maybe the csv has `"` in it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the CSV data is quoting the fields, you need to use the [`ENCLOSED BY` option](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html#load-data-field-line-handling):

```
mysqli_query($cons, '
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE "crypto/blog/csv/' . $file . '"
    INTO TABLE ' . $table . '
    FIELDS TERMINATED by \',\' ENCLOSED BY \'"\'
    LINES TERMINATED BY \'\n\'
 ');
```